# Probability of Rolling a total of an 11 or 12 given the following circumstances...

Tags: probability, dice

What is the probability of rolling a total of an 11 or 12 given the following circumstances...

1. you get to roll THREE dice and pick any TWO.
2. you get to roll THREE dice and pick any TWO, you may also reroll ONE of the dice before selecting the two.
   *Note we are assuming a six side die with equal chance to roll a 1-6.

Probability of rolling a 6 is 1/6 and probability of rolling a 5 OR 6 is 2/6. Is the correct way to go about this (2/6)+(1/6)+(1/6) = 0.65 or 65% chance, them seems way too high

I'm not even sure how to go about calculating when you get to reroll a single dice.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Please show us what you've attempted

Comment: How many possible outcomes are there when rolling 3 dice? How many of those outcomes include at least two sixes? How many include a single six and at least one five?